# Determining the values for an array within limits

Tags: recreational-mathematics

So I did some math on a function to produce positions within an array of which I wanted to record data.  My initial math looked like this:

$$ (n * \frac{100}{n})-1$$

This would allow me to determine the upper limit of the array, and then I could capture the data in each position of that multiple...

ex if $n = 7$:
The first array set of values would be 0, 7, 14, 21...98
The second array 1, 8, 15, 22...99
The third 2, 9, 16, 23...93

What I was trying to do was determine the max multiple of $n$ in 0-99.  This worked for the values that we were initially given.  $n$ could have been 7 or 8.  Now, the customer has requested that the value range be 5 to 8.  This produced a signifigant problem because the result of the above formula became 100 when $n$ was 5.  The array upper bounds is 99, so we can't use the value of 100.  How can I change the formula so that it can be an all in one solution and we don't have to worry about limits?  Basically, the value produced should be the greatest multiple of $n$ that is 99 or less, minus 1.

Ex:

$n=8$ should produce a value of 95 $8*12-1$

$n=7$ should produce a value of 97 $7*14-1$

$n=6$ should produce a value of 95 $6*16-1$

$n=5$ should produce a value of 99 $5*20-1$

$n=4$ should produce a value of 95 $4*24-1$

Comment: Please recheck your calculations: 95 = 8*12-1 and 95 = 6*16-1.

Comment: @Crazyformaths done, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum multiple of a number in $0-99$ is given by $\Big[\frac{99}{n}\Big]\times n$ (where [.] is the greatest integer function).

Hope it is helpful:)

Comment: So basically you're telling me if I didn't over complicate the firsts formula, I wouldn't be having this problem? :P

Comment: Uhg, you're right.  Don't know how I missed that.  Thanks!